# Php Programming Error (Can't run the while loop)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

<?php
    session_start();

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");

    $product_code = $_GET['product_code'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_config WHERE product_code = '$product_code'";
    $product_list = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql);

    if($product_list = 1)
    echo"good";
    else
    echo"bad"; 
?>
</head>

<body>

<span id="tttt"></span>
<form id="msform" method="post">
<!-- progressbar -->
<ul id="progressbar">
<li class="active">

<?php While ($one_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_list)) {?>


<li><?php echo $one_product['test_name']; ?></li>

<?php } ?>

<!-- <a href="index.html" >Start-Over</a>  -->
<span onclick="window.close()" style="float:right">Start-Over</span>
</ul>

<?php While ( $one_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_list)  ) { 

        $num_test = $one_product['num_test'];
        $test_name = $one_product['test_name'];
        $images_pos = $one_product['images_pos'];
        $images_neg = $one_product['images_neg'];
        $images_inv = $one_product['images_inv'];
?>
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset id="<?php $test_name; ?>" data-set="0">
<h2 class="fs-title"><?php echo "$test_name"; ?></h2>
<img src="images/<?php $images_pos; ?>"  class="case" data-case="1"/><br/>
<input name="<?php $test_name; ?>" type="radio" value="N" class="hide">
<img src="images/<?php $images_neg; ?>"  class="case" data-case="2"/><br/>
<input name="<?php $test_name; ?>" type="radio" value="P" class="hide">
<img src="images/<?php $images_inv; ?>"  class="case" data-case="3"/><br/>
<input name="<?php $test_name; ?>" type="radio" value="I" class="hide">
<img src="images/skip_button.fw.png"  class="case" data-case="4"/><br/>
<input name="<?php $test_name; ?>" type="radio" value="S" class="hide">
<br/>

<?php if ($num_test > 1) { ?>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />

<br/>
<?php if($num_test == 1) { ?>

<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="action-button" value="SAVE" />

</fieldset>
<?php }
$num_test --; ?>
<?php } }?>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Errors: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, integer given on line 41 and line 52 (Line that contain )

Please help me thanks!!!!! The sql does get the data from the database. However, the while loop is still having some errors.

Comment: check if condition with double equal: `if($product_list == 1)`

Comment: The syntax of your if statement right before the closing `</head>` tag needs some work. Use `==` for evals and your missing some `{`

Comment: @blazerunner44 the curly braces aren't required when there's only one line of condition, although I agree in principle that they should always be used

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if($product_list = 1)
    echo"good";
    else
    echo"bad";

Shouldnt be there. As it will make $product_list into boolean and thus cannot run through the loop

Answer (score 0):

This happens usually when the mysqli_query hasnt run properly,

Try this

```
if (!$query) {
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out soon.

Comment: I tried to add the line of code inside but it show error in the line containing your codes. Only 'MySQL Error:' was display, the error wasn't there

Comment: Have you change variable $query to $product_list in above code ?

Comment: No i didnt. But if i change it, it is the same old error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error with your query. Could you please replace your code with this? It should provide you with an error message telling what is off in your query.
If I were to take a guess, I would say that `$product_code` is stored as an integer in the database but you are using it as a string in your query.

```
$product_list = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out soon.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from your variable in your query `$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_config WHERE product_code = $product_code";` If this still gives you an error, please post the error it gives you here.

Comment: Hi, the same problem occur. <?php While ($one_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_list)) {?> is the line with error

Comment: Somemore since my product_code is a String, it do need the quotes. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Is the product_code field in your database a string too? Can you post the error you get from the mysqli_error($conn) code in my answer?

Comment: Yes. String. It is the same old error. -->   While ($one_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_list)) {?>

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, integer given in line 40,51

Comment: Looks like you got it figured out.